# Do these dry rotted tires need to be replaced immediately?

Tags: tires, sidewall

I’m leaning to the safe side and saying yes. How bad is it and does the water-based seal strategy work at all or that just blog snakeoil?

[image: tread]

[image: sidewall]

Comment: AFAIK the sealant products are only intended for low speed off-road use (e.g. ride on mowers, hand carts, etc). They are ***not*** safe to use at highway speeds.

Comment: If the tyres have perished they won't be as strong or as flexible as original. My Ford car at 14 years old (low mileage) was on original rear tyres. The repair shop refused to mend a puncture, not because it was near the edge (it wasn't), but because they could not guarantee the tyre would be safe after removing and refitting. SO I bought new tyres. BTW I notice the tread at the edge of your tyre is badly worn. Time to replace the tyres?

Comment: I, personally, wouldn't take issue with using those tires

Answer (score 2):

Tires with advanced dry rot must be replaced. Dry rot allows air to escape the tire, making it difficult or even impossible to keep the tire properly inflated. Dry rot can also cause unnatural rubber expansion while driving that actually breaks the tire apart. Tires with dry rot are much more likely to develop leaks, holes, and blow outs. Bottom line, get them replaced it's not worth the risk to you and your family.